Angular 17 Not Receiving Message From Spring WebSocket
This is my service on Angular. It successfully connects and sends a message:
export class WebsocketService {

    private stompClient:any;
    private isConnectedSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    constructor() {
        this.initializeWebSocketConnection();
    }

    initializeWebSocketConnection() {
        const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws');

        this.stompClient = new Client({
            webSocketFactory: () => socket,
            debug: (str: string) => {
            console.log(str);
            },
        });

        this.stompClient.activate();
        this.isConnectedSubject.next(true); // Notify connected state
    }


    public subscribe(queue: string, callback: (message:any) => void): void {
        this.stompClient.subscribe(queue, callback);
    }

    public send(queue: string, message: string, headers: any = {}): void {
        this.stompClient.publish({
            destination: queue,
            body: message,
            headers: headers
        });
    }
}

Here is a screenshot when I try to send a message:
browser:

Spring Boot logs:

Here is my component:
export class VideoItemComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private websocketService: WebsocketService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Example subscription to '/queue/example'
    }
    
    subscribe() {
        this.websocketService.subscribe('/topic/1', (message: any) => {
          console.log('Received message:', message.body);
          // Handle message processing here
        });
    }
    send(): void {
        const video:Video = {
            videoId:1,
            status:"HELLO",
            dateRequested:null,
            url:"hello",
        }

        const messageToSend = JSON.stringify(video);
        const destinationQueue = '/app/send/1';
        const headers = {
          // Optionally, add headers here if needed
        };

        this.websocketService.send(destinationQueue, messageToSend, headers);
    }
}

Here is my Spring Boot app:
Config class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/all","/specific");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}

Controller:
@Controller
public class MessageController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    public MessageController(final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate = simpMessagingTemplate;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/application")
    @SendTo("/all")
    public Video send(final Video message) throws Exception {
        return message;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/send/{videoId}") // This handles messages prefixed with /app/send/{videoId}
    public void sendMessageToTopic(@Payload  Video video) {
        // Send message to specific topic based on videoId
        System.out.println(video);
        String topic = "/topic/" + video.getVideoId();
        System.out.println(topic);
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(topic, video);
    }
}

How can I make my Angular app receive the message sent to the topic it subscribes to?

First off, is your Angular app actually subscribed to the topic where you're sending the message? As far as I can tell nothing actually calls subscribe.
